# Изучение ассемблера не зная высокоуровневых языков

Tags: ассемблер

Можно ли изучать ассемблер не зная высокоуровневые языки?

Comment: Разумеется. Я бы даже сказал, что это предпочтительно, пока языки высокого уровня не наложили на мышление свои рамки. Лично у меня ассемблер был первым языком и я никогда об этом не жалел.

Comment: Можно, но тут 2 вещи необходимы : иметь понимание, как работает компьютер и уметь программировать, т.е уметь составить программу; если же вы никогда не программировали ни в коем случае не начинайте с ассемблера, вы просто разочаруетесь в жизни; а по сути лучше сначала научиться работать с С, а потом уже переходить к ассемблеру

Comment: Зависит от цели. В большинстве случаев - нет. И гарантированно нет, если нет цели. Впрочем, тогда и ЯВУ изучать нет смысла.

Comment: @Akina imho ассемблер очень способствует достижению цели "научиться программировать", потому как учит понимать машину и строить алгоритмы

Comment: Если вы не умеете программировать, то начинать с ассемблера не стоит. Лучше сначала на основе более простого языка освоить основные алгоритмы и структуры данных. В противном случае вы познаете очень много боли.

Comment: Зависит от образа мышления. Мы все слишком разные. Мне пришлось изучать ассемблер, уже зная несколько высокоуровневых языков. Возможно, это привело к тому, что у меня свой подход к программированию на ассемблере. В любом случае, сейчас ассемблер редко когда нужен, как самостоятельный инструмент, чаще он необходим для решения локальных задач, как правило, связанных с эффективностью кода.

Comment: Запросто. Лтчно я учился эффективному программированию еще на Б3-21, потом Б3-34 - куда там ассемблеру... Очень, очень способствует приобретению полезных навыков :)

Comment: @Mike Я учился программировать "от железа к программе" в машинных кодах, у меня вообще альтернативы не было - только АСМ. Оттого до сих пор считаю все ЯВУ недоделанными уродами - ассемблер делает так, как я сказал, а ЯВУ - как он хочет...

Comment: @Akina Пора проводить исследование "зависимость рейтинга SO от порядка изучения языков программирования" :) Что то мне подсказывает, что ассемблер/машкод будет преобладать как один из первых языков у большинства топов :)

Comment: @Harry, я с МК-61 начинал. У нас тут кстати пару вопросов по нему было: [tag:МК-61].

Comment: @insolor Практически Б3-34. На МК-61 я нашел недокументированную команду, отправил ее в "Химию и жизнь" - там тогда этим занимались, печатали... Как сейчас помню - был там такой Жвирблис - послал меня, мол, это никому не нужно. Через месяца 3 это появилось уже в "Науке и жизни", понятно, не под моим именем...